# Catalyst app window size won't go below 670 x 481

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm trying to resize the window size to be as small as I want, but can't.

If I do this on my SceneDelegate:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 100)
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = MainViewController()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

It still won't work, it does get smaller than by default but the minimum size is always 670 x 481. How can I make it go lower than that? While the window still being resizable.
The size of the window can be set to a smaller size, but I want to achieve the smaller size when the user resizes it, not in code.